# Using client credential flow on Graph api returns an access_token without scopes

Tags: azure, graph, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Here is what my goal is: I would like to get an access_token from within my api. Currently I am trying to get the access token using the client credentials flow:
[image]

And I successfully get a response:
[image]

But this response does nothing because when I use the access_token as authorization parameter in a GraphApi endpoint I get an error response saying I am `missing scp or roles` parameters. I have roles defined and approved from an administrator from the application. What could be the problem?

Here is the decoded jwt access_token:

```
{
  "aud": "a********************ed5",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/**********4f-d6b581dd3836/",
  "iat": 1660825101,
  "nbf": 1660825101,
  "exp": 1660829001,
  "aio": "E2ZgYPits***********g8R9TAA==",
  "appid": "eabbd3*************da6990ed5",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/5a8f9d89-81da-4218-884f-d6b581dd3836/",
  "oid": "77e***************8085325",
  "rh": "0.AYEAiZ2PWtqBGEKIT9a1gd04NuDTu-rpzyZCiMRhXaaZDtWBAAA.",
  "sub": "77e4***************48085325",
  "tid": "5a8f9d89-8*****************581dd3836",
  "uti": "nl-kk3T*******w2ePAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one App Role named **`DemoRole`** for my Azure AD application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> App Roles*

[image]

**I assigned that `DemoRole` to few users like below:**

*Go to Azure -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> Your App -> Users and groups*

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** with parameters like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id = xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
grant_type = client_credentials
client_secret = ***************
scope = api://xxxxxxx.xxxx.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the token, I'm also unable to get the roles like below:

[image]

To get **`roles`** claim in decoded token, make sure to add your custom API permissions and grant admin consent like below:

***Go to your Application -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> My APIs -> Your App Name -> Application Permissions***

[image]

After granting the admin consent, I generated the access token again and got the **`roles`** claim in the decoded token like below:

[image]

Comment: Now can you use the access_token to call a graph api endpoint?

Comment: ```{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-19T07:13:20",
            "request-id": "c423a65d-ae5a-438b-b9f9-66f838c51521",
            "client-request-id": "c423a65d-ae5a-438b-b9f9-66f838c51521"
        }
    }
}
``` 

This is the response I get when trying to use the access_token in a request.

Comment: To call graph Api endpoint, you need to get access token using scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Comment: That is because I used this ``api://*********4226-88c4-615da6990ed5/.default`` in the scope parameter when obtaining  the access token. I should use ``https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`` instead, but then I don't get the 'roles' object inside my access token when decoding it.

Comment: I don't get the roles when I use that scope

Comment: This is the error I get when using the graph.microsoft.com/.default.
``"Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.",``

Comment: Could you please provide the query you are using to call graph api?

Comment: PUT ``https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/f9484969-2e6b-451d-bc8f-60642868b326/drives/b!aUlI-WsuHUW8j2BkKGizJrvZ2ZuGzqVPrtYRlas6YCZenycL1VeSRKsskzuYq-t0/root:/Izjava2.pdf:/content`` I am trying to upload a document.

Comment: Modify token endpoint by replacing **common** with your **TenantID** and generate token with `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope like **[this](https://i.imgur.com/QSJHPLz.png)**

Comment: I am using the TennantId and not common. That does not work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247384/discussion-between-sridevi-m-and-matejdodevski).